# required dependencies with specific versions

Tags: protocol-buffers, nix, grpc

I'm trying to build libgrpc as a nixpkg on OS X.
It depends on zlib, protobuf >= 3.0 and openssl >= 1.0.2.

How can I specify these versions as the minimum? Both are contained in the official channel and both built successfully.

I'm pretty new to nix and this is my attempt to get my feet wet.
For now, this is what I have for `default.nix`:

```
{ stdenv, fetchurl, zlib, openssl, protobuf }:

stdenv.mkDerivation rec {
  name = "libgrpc-0.10.1";

  src = fetchurl {
    url = "https://github.com/grpc/grpc/archive/release-0_10_1.tar.gz";
    sha256 = "2da8deef4fcc421ce8e9102e8531261b3c23073ab4d2bf459e549ed4e37b5ba1";
  };

  buildInputs = [zlib "openssl-1.0.2d" "protobuf-3.0.0-alpha-3.1"];

  meta = {
    homepage = "https://github.com/grpc/grpc/";
    version = "0.10.1";
    description = "A library for a RPC service based on HTTP/2 and protobuf";
    license = stdenv.lib.licenses.bsd3;
    platforms = [
      "i686-linux"
      "x86_64-linux"
      "x86_64-darwin"
      "i686-cygwin"
      "i686-freebsd"
      "x86_64-freebsd"
      "i686-openbsd"
      "x86_64-openbsd"
    ];
    downloadPage = "https://github.com/grpc/grpc/archive/release-0_10_1.tar.gz";
  };
}
```

I'm either looking for a way to either build libgrpc > 0.10 under nix - or for a wayto define minimum versions for requirements so I can try to fix this myself.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A look inside `all-packages.nix` showed that these versions are available as `openssl_1_0_2` and `protobuf3_0`.

I'm still stuck at a zlib-dependency problem, but the problem I asked about is solved.